# If I cast Hex on my familiar as a Pact of the Chain warlock, can I use the Relentless Hex eldritch invocation to teleport next to it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, teleportation, eldritch-invocations

If I'm a Pact of the Chain warlock and I cast *hex* on my familiar, can I use the Relentless Hex eldritch invocation to teleport next to my familiar as a bonus action for the duration of the *hex* spell?

Comment: Hi there Knarf. The body of your question makes sense (and is a good question) but the title doesn't seem to relate to the body. Are you asking the question in the title (which isn't a full question), or the body?

Comment: I guess I'm asking if what I suggested in the body is a way to teleport the most.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I've edited the title to match the body, since your main question seems to be about whether this method works in the first place (it's not clear what you mean by "teleport the most").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, you can

Answering the question asked in the body, the text of the [Hex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hex) spell does not require that the target be an enemy:

> You place a curse on a creature that you can see within range

so you can target any creature that you can see. The text of [Relentless Hex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/subclasses#EldritchInvocations) simply requires:

> As a bonus action, you can magically teleport up to 30 feet to an
>   unoccupied space you can see within 5 feet of the target cursed by
>   your *hex* spell or by a warlock feature of yours [...] you must be
>   able to see the cursed target.

So you can Hex your familiar, and you can then use your Relentless Hex invocation to teleport within 5 feet of it so long as you can see it, the space you wish to teleport to, and both are within 30' of you.

Comment: May be helpful to mention that the the most this functionally gives you is an extra 30' of movement at the cost of a bonus action.

Comment: Thanks nautarch that's an interesting way of viewing it. Since most of the familiars fly it also means you could move in any direction, regardless of terrain, for that bonus action.  Or even to the other side of a barrier like a portcullis as long as your familiar is within 5 feet of it.  Or behind your enemies.

Comment: Potentially you could look through your familiar's eyes and still use this

Comment: Using the familiar's eyes would be handy for scouting and then popping in.